# Prerequisite to read Ravi Vakil's Foundation of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, self-learning, advice

Can I start to read his lecture notes after I had taken Commutative Algebra and basic topology (up to the fundamental group and covering space)?

Comment: Not a big fan of questions like this. How about you just start reading it, and see how far you can get?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Vakil's notes, but for Hartshorne, you need to know a good deal of commutative algebra and, later in the book, homological algebra. You do also need very basic topology.